# Does logging and the like break REST

Tags: rest

Recollecting from what I know about REST (REpresentational State Transfer), there are certain "safe" HTTP methods like the GET request which is not supposed to invoke change on a server.

There are a lot of great RESTful API's out there and one thing I notice is many of them will limit the number of requests you can make over a period of time.  Wouldn't monitoring GET requests technically break REST since keeping track of the requests requires change on the server?

Or is there a completely RESTful way to keep track of GET requests?

Comment: I would think that's something about the API that has nothing to do with REST.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol#Safe_methods)

> Some methods (for example, HEAD, GET, OPTIONS and TRACE) are defined
>   as safe, which means they are intended only for information retrieval
>   and should not change the state of the server. In other words, they
>   should not have side effects, beyond relatively harmless effects such
>   as logging, caching, the serving of banner advertisements or
>   incrementing a web counter. Making arbitrary GET requests without
>   regard to the context of the application's state should therefore be
>   considered safe.

This is true for the REST requests also.

Answer (score 0):

Monitoring usage is usually a different layer than the application layer. So the REST API is one thing, while usage tracking is another thing.

In addition, while REST is an architectural style, we should not bend reality to comply with it. We can sometimes ignore things that "break" an architecture, but we should do so only after thinking about the consequences. Being fanatic about architecture is not a good practice what so ever...

Comment: Even if the monitoring happens at a different layer, it still is changing the state of server.

Comment: @VaishakSuresh, it depends on your definition of "server". You can see the REST request as a usage request that happens to be in REST (it could also be a WSDL+SOAP web service request), that goes first through a usage counter layer, and then goes to the application layer. The usage layer is a totally different application, not bound to REST concepts, hence its server may (and should) be modified what so ever.

Comment: While I agree with most of what you are saying, I would still think the usage layer and the applications as the applications and not the server. Web Server/ Application Container can be viewed as a server, but a J2EE application cannot be viewed as a server. In case of REST, the Web/Application server is changing state.

Answer (score 0):

If you think of the semantics of the HTTP method from the perspective of the client then it is easier to understand the purpose of the "safe" semantic.  From the client's point of view, it is issuing a request without any **intent** to change any state on the server.  If the server chooses to make state changes as a result, then that's the server's choice and the client cannot be considered responsible for those changes.